Iced water on burns
I would like to understand why iced water on a thermal burn makes it worse. I read the following statements:

burns could end up deeper because of the vasoconstriction induced by iced water
iced water makes a thermal shock because of the brutal temperature change.

I would like to really understand the mechanisms involved.

What is the source of the quotes you provided?
